# Firebase API call with multiple topics in condition

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing a tragic issue while calling FCM API:-
In brief When I am calling the API with following:

```
URL:-https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AAAA4Kkj8iw:APA91bE......vE4Hxg
{
    "condition" : "'Software' in topics",
    "data":{
        "title":"Title",
        "message":"Hello,Via Multiple Topics"
    }
}
```

It works Fine and I got the notification on device from which I have subscribed to topic "Software", But when I go for multiple topics and change the body to

```
{
    "condition" : "'Software' in topics || 'IOT' in topics",
    "data":{
        "title":"Title",
        "message":"Hello,Via Multiple Topics"
    }
}
```

then I don't get the notification
I have tested it on POSTMAN it shows that message was sent but I don't receive any notification on my device.

Comment: Tried it out on my end. I also used Postman. Only subscribed to `Software` topic, sent the payload with multiple topics. Works okay.

Comment: Also works for me, Did you mean to use '||' over '&&'?

Comment: no I need to use '||' no need of '&&' my use case is to send notification to user if he is subscribed to any of these topics. I don't understand why it is not working for me, Is there any extra config. required at android side in order to receive notification from multiple topics??

Comment: It's a bug. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48256616/firebase-send-message-to-multiple-topics/48284762#48284762

Answer (score 3):

This is the right way as per the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#topic-http-post-request):

### Topic HTTP POST request

#### Send to a single topic:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
{
  "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
   }
}
```

#### Send to devices subscribed to topics "dogs" or "cats":

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
{
  "condition": "'dogs' in topics || 'cats' in topics",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
   }
}
```

Comment: It's a bug confirmed by Google. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48256616/firebase-send-message-to-multiple-topics/48284762#48284762