# Firebase Send Message to Multiple Topics

Tags: firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been trying to send cloud messages to users who subscribed to multiple topics through an API call (POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send) with the following body:

```
{
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer MY_ACCESS_TOKEN`
  },
  body: {
    "message": {
      "condition": "'cat' in topics || 'dog' in topics",
      "notification": {
        "title": "Message Title",
        "body": "Message Body" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote this config according to the [FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#build_send_requests). I can get a response similar to this:

```
{
  "name": "projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages/5735743068807585451"
}
```

but no messages were received by any devices.

I've used the access token for other APIs, which works. I'm also aware that the FCM documentation also provided a different body for the cURL request, which I also tried but not working.

The weird thing is if I only provide one topic in the `condition`, a message is actually successfully sent to subscribed devices. Am I writing something wrong?

I've already referenced other solutions on Stackoverflow but everything is still not working:

[Firebase API call with multiple topics in condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41800879/firebase-api-call-with-multiple-topics-in-condition)

[How to send FCM Push Notifications to multiple topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413037/how-to-send-fcm-push-notifications-to-multiple-topics)

Answer (score 17):

After talking to Firebase Support, they pointed out the problem I'm having here is a known bug they are still trying to fix. And there's no specific timeline for a fix yet.

Therefore, there's no problem with my code and I'll have to figure out a workaround myself if I really want to use the "||"(OR) operator.

My current workaround is keep track of subscribers with a database (since Firebase doesn't offer subscribers querying), then implement the OR condition myself by finding a union of subscribers to different topics.

[image]

P.S. I just don't get why the downvotes, I actually found a bug here and referenced all the solutions I could found on SO before asking the question here.

Comment: Do you know whether Firebase team has fixed it or not?

Comment: @tom10271 AFAIK, they changed the documentation to saying for now they can only support two logical operators, I haven't tested it though.

Comment: I have asked Firebase Support team and they reply they can now support up to 5 topics and limited 2 conditions criteria is gone. They will update document accordingly with no exact expected day though.

Comment: For some reason I'm having the same issue using this: 'Firestone' in topics || 'second' in topics|| 'another' in topics .. It don't work, but If I sent to one topic it works